# how can I close the UITextView keyboard using the Return key in an app using SpriteKit and Swift?

Tags: swift, keyboard, sprite-kit, return, uitextview

My app uses SpriteKit, but I also use UITextView to capture some user data as part of the game.  Everything works fine, except when I try to close the UITextView's keyboard using the Return key.  It looks like everything is there in my code to get the keyboard to close in this way.  I've set the UITextView to self delegate, used the textView function to close the keyboard, but nothing happens. There are no errors reported.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Is it because I'm using didMoveToView() maybe?

```
import SpriteKit
import UIKit

class GameScene: SKScene, UITextViewDelegate {

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    /* Setup your scene here */

    backgroundColor = SKColor.redColor()

    let myProjectView = UITextView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 100.0, height: 200.0))
    myProjectView.center = CGPointMake(300.0, 350.0)
    myProjectView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    self.view?.addSubview(myProjectView)

    // Close keyboard
    myProjectView.delegate = self

    func textView(textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextInRange range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
        myProjectView.text = textView.text
        println("step 1")
        if text == "\n" {
            println("step 2")
            textView.resignFirstResponder()
            return false
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: does it print out "step 2" from your function? In that case. perhaps try `self.view.endEditing(true)` instead of `textView.resignFirstResponder()`

Comment: I forgot to mention that, neither of the println statements print anything

Comment: You have to declare your func textView outside the function didMoveToView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving the UITTextView declaration and the original textView func outside the didMoveToView func gets the Return key to dismiss the keyboard

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to dismiss the keyboard:

```
func yourTextView(textView: UITextView!, shouldChangeTextInRange: NSRange, replacementText: NSString!) -> Bool {
        if (replacementText == "\n")  {
            yourTextView.resignFirstResponder()
            return false
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

Try copying and pasting the above code. This worked for me. I am unsure where the error is in your code but I know this code works to dismiss the keyboard so please try it.

I hope this can help you with the problem you are having.

Comment: He is using a textView, (I'm not an expert) but I don't think UITextView has a textViewShouldReturn delegate?

Comment: Yes. you are correct. I will edit my code. I thought it was a UITextField not a TextView.

Comment: I tried the alternative code but it still doesn't work . It looks like the function isn't being called because the first println which I placed above the if doesn't get called. I think this might be something to do with spritekit?

Comment: Did you try using an `if-else` statement for the 2 `println()s`?